# Jquery if then changing td background color sharepoint

Tags: jquery, html, sharepoint

I would like to, my current code is not:
1. Show section 1 of html if condition 1 exists
2. Show section 2 of html if condition 2 exists
3. Otherwise hide section 2 and show section 1
4. If Condition 1 then change the background color of TD id "ATA" to: #d6e8ff
5. If Condition 2 then change the background color of TD id "QGA" to: #d6e8ff
6. I need to keep the "(".ms-sitemapdirectional").text()=='ARMARTApplication Approval Transition by Phase')" since it is how I am grabbing the current page in sharepoint.

```
<head>
<script src="/sites/ADMRun/SiteCollectionDocuments/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    //alert($(".ms-sitemapdirectional").text());
    var showItem = function (.ms-sitemapdirectional, div) {
    if($(".ms-sitemapdirectional").text()=='ARMARTApplication Approval Transition by Phase'){
        $("#DOCMGT").attr("href","http://www.yahoo.com"); //Application Approval Link
        $("#DOCMGTP").attr("href","http://www.yahoo.com"); //Application Approval Link
        $("#QGATE").attr("href","http://www.yahoo.com"); //Quality Gate List Link
        $("#ATA").addClass('color');
        $("#QGA").removeClass('color'); //No background color
        $("#section1").removeClass('hide');
        $("#section2").addClass('hide'); //Hide section
        }
    else ($(".ms-sitemapdirectional").text()=='ARMARTQuality Gate Approvals by Phase'){
        $("#DOCMGT").attr("href","http://www.yahoo.com"); //Application Approval Link
        $("#DOCMGTP").attr("href","http://www.yahoo.com"); //Application Approval Link
        $("#QGATE").attr("href","http://www.yahoo.com"); //Quality Gate List Link
        $("#QGA").addClass('color');
        $("#ATA").removeClass('color'); //No background color
        $("#section2").removeClass('hide');
        $("#section1").addClass('hide'); //Hide section
        }
    };

    // register a listener to the links
    $('#changer a').on('click', function () {
        var itemId = $(this).attr('id');
        var .ms-sitemapdirectional = $(this).text();

        showItem(linkText);
    });
}); 
    </script>
</head>

<!--I don't want to have additional urls above the table-->
<div id="changer"> 
<a href="#" class="ms-sitemapdirectional">INFOKEEP</a> | <a href="#" class="ms-sitemapdirectional">INFONOTKEPT</a> | <a href="#" class="ms-sitemapdirectional">INFOSOMETHINGELSE</a>
</div>

<TABLE style="WIDTH: 100%" border=1 summary="Document Approvals">
<TBODY>
<TR>

<!--This section should control the href attributes from the jquery-->
<TD><A id=DOCMGTP><IMG border=0 src="http://placekitten.com/g/100/100"></A></TD>
<TD id=ATA><FONT size=2><STRONG><A id=DOCMGT>Application Transition Approvals</A></STRONG></FONT></TD>
<TD id=QGA class="color"><FONT size=2><STRONG><A id=QGATE>Quality Gate Approvals</A></STRONG></FONT></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>

<!--Section 1-->
<div id="section1" class="hide">
<BR><STRONG>Instructions:</STRONG> Use this Document Approval tool to track Application Transition Approvals by Phase.<BR>
<STRONG><EM>Documents are to be located</EM></STRONG>: /<B><I><SPAN style="COLOR: #00b050">COE Name</SPAN></I></B>/Shared Documents/Project Management/Quality Gate/
<B><I><SPAN style="COLOR: #00b050">Application Name/Phase Name (Unique folder for each application and phase per application)</SPAN>&nbsp;</I></B>
</div>

<!--Section 2-->
<div id="#section2" class="hide">        
<STRONG>Instructions:</STRONG> Use this Document Approval tool to track Quality Gate Approvals by Phase.<BR>
<STRONG><EM>Documents are to be located</EM></STRONG>: /<B><I><SPAN style="COLOR: #00b050">COE Name</SPAN></I></B>/Shared Documents/Project Management/Quality Gate/
</div>
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I revised your code and compiled it into a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UTz6H/1/ - I hope it is enough to get you going...

Comment: @blurfus I implemented and still having challenges, this is my first attempt at jquery and such. thanks for your help.

Comment: can you verify that you are loading jquery?  the url in the code above is not reachable to me...  Also, can you give me further indication of what is not working (any JS errors? are you using IE? etc)

Comment: jquery works, no errors, IE 9.
The sections aren't hiding.
I am having the jquery set the url from an attr and that stopped working too.